# Syntax error: invalid label

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem of `Syntax error: invalid label` when I call a REST service by AJAX in cross domain. My response is `{ "d": 12000 }` it shows the error at the double quote on "d".

My code is like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost/test.svc/getnumber',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/jsonp",
});
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: url:'http:localhost//test.svc/getnumber

Comment: I think you have to add a comma after url: 'http://localhost//test.svc/getnumber'

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because your server doesn't return a JSONP value; it should use the value of `callback` from the request query string and return a piece of JavaScript code that contains a function call.

For example, `$.ajax()` will send a request to `/path/to/script?callback=jsonp_12123123`, so your server should return:

```
jsonp_12123123({"d": 12000})
```

With PHP you can accomplish this using:

```
<?php

// DO NOT USE AS IS, SANITIZE $_GET!!!
echo $_GET['callback'], '(', json_encode(array(
    'd' => 12000,
)), ')';
```

Also, you don't need the `contentType: 'application/jsonp'`; it would be sent to the server, but you're posting any data, so it's useless.

Comment: @user2000423 You can't do it within JavaScript for sure, and you haven't shown the server code :)

Comment: @user2000423 I know your server side returns the number, but it should return something else; that's my point. jQuery will send a query string parameter called `callback` which you need to use in the output. That's how jsonp works.

Comment: so how i use callback in output.

Comment: @user2000423 I've given an example in PHP, hope that gives you an idea.

Comment: Why not change `jsonp` to `json`? Why change input to match the output?

Comment: @salmanA because it's most likely being used for cross site requests.

Comment: @user2000453 you can't fix cross site requests in the same page as your JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost/test.svc/getnumber',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

There's mistake in the `url` and by [specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) your content type should be `application/json`.

Comment: my actual code is like this...$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: Service_Url + "/GetClientDeviceNumber",
contentType: "application/jsonp",
crossDomain: true,
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function (response) {
$.session.set("DEVICE_NUMBER", response);
}
});

Comment: Change the contentType to `application/json` without `p` at the end.

Comment: Changing `contentType` won't help, because the script is not sending any data.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, you have a malformed URL (double `//`), there's also an issue with your `contentType`, it needs to be `application/json`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost/test.svc/getnumber',
    datatype: "jsonp",
    contentType: 'application/json',
});
```

Comment: Changing `contentType` won't help, as no data is being sent to the server.